# Android - как отправлять запрос с периодичностью 10 секунд на сервер?

Tags: java, android

Как отправлять запрос с периодичностью  10 секунд на сервер? Я использую библиотеку okhttp, скиньте пример, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //Тут идёт запрос в сеть
    }
}
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

RxJava, с лямбдами

```
Observable.just(true).repeatWhen(t->t.delay(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)).subscribe(b->{makeNetworkRequest();});
```

Без лямбд

```
Observable.just(true).repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Void> t) {
                return t.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }).subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Boolean b) {
                makeNetworkRequest();
            }
        });
```

Comment: как остановить его?

Comment: @Suleymanovtat добавьте перед `subscribe` `.takeUntil(condition)`

Answer (score 1):

В Android предоставлено множество способов создать таймер. Запрос на сервер через библиотеку `okhttp` можно сделать синхронным в отдельном потоке. Мой пример с созданием рекурсии, без использования `Timer` и `TimerTask`.

```
 static boolean stopSyncDownloadData = false;

 /**
 * Call method in thread
 * @param stopSyncDownloadData - boolean
 */

private void syncDownloadData()
{
    if (stopSyncDownloadData)
        return;
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    // parse response
    // update UI
    // delay Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep
    syncDownloadingData();
}
```

Ниже пример для создания простейшего потока:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            syncDownloadData();
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что так лучше не делать, так как приложение через некоторое время вылетит с StackOverflowError.